Android Sign in Bitrise
I am tring to move my signingConfigs into bitrise
release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH") ?: "./dummy/path")
            storePassword System.getenv("BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }

This code is groovy but while building I am getting  Android Build (Failed) with such error
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningProductionRelease'.
> Keystore file '/bitrise/src/app/dummy/path' not found for signing config 'release'.

After uploding my keystore into bitrise "Code signing" I added Androis sign step before Android Build.
From error it is clear thant I am not getting getting BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH so elvis been used, however Android sign is downloading key and creating path for file, after consistently failing I added script between android sign and android build to set BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH manually.
export BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH=$(find /tmp -name "keystore.jks" | head -n 1)
echo "Dynamically set BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH to $BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"```

But still getting same error.
 


I found the answer, you need to remove signingConfigs from the build.gradle, an android sign will do it automatically, but in that case you won't be able to run release on your device so come up with some if else logic where you will check if you running on CI or locally
